# Exchange JSON between Java and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, json, sockets, websocket

I would like to send JSON data from a Java Application to a JavaScript. The JSON is log/statistical data which I would like to format with JavaScript and view in the browser in realtime.

I tried it through a `Socket` but JavaScript's `WebSocket` does not really accept the `Socket` from Java. Firefox tells me that it `can't establish an connection to ws://localhost:8000`.

**Java Socket**

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

out.println("Message");
```

**JavaScript WebSocket**

```
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000");

exampleSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
    console.log(event.data);
};
```

If this is not possible because of incompatability. What would be the simplest way to send JSON to JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a WebSocket implementation for Java:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Then under Server Side Implementations > Java > Jetty
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/